# Fill NA only between 2 same non-NA values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to fill NAs of a pandas series by the non-NAs values, but only if the non-NA values padding the NA values are the same.  Is there any clever fast solution? I know I could write a function which I would use in the itterrows setting but I am operating with millions of rows and need a faster solution.

Example of Input:

```
0    NaN
1    1
2    NaN
3    1
4    NaN
5    2
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    2
9    NaN
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    NaN
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit cheeky, but my first idea is to check where `ffill` and `bfill` would fill the same value.

```
>>> s
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    1.0
4    NaN
5    2.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    2.0
9    NaN
dtype: float64
>>> ffill = s.ffill()
>>> s[ffill.eq(s.bfill())] = ffill
>>> s
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    NaN
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    2.0
9    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Seems to be the simplest and most efficient idea ;)

Comment: Thanks! This is fast even on large dataframes